# How to make browser storage persistent on MacOS?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, persistence, progressive-web-apps, indexeddb

I want to persist my data in a IndexedDB.

This is my code:

```
if (navigator.storage && navigator.storage.persist)
  navigator.storage.persist().then(granted => {
    if (granted)
      alert("Storage will not be cleared except by explicit user action");
    else
      alert("Storage may be cleared by the UA under storage pressure.");
  });
```

I read this article: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/persistent-storage

> Beginning with Chrome 55, Chrome will automatically grant the
>   persistence permission if any of the following are true:
>
> The site is bookmarked (and the user has 5 or less bookmarks)
>
> The site has high site engagement
>
> The site has been added to home screen
>
> The site has push notifications enabled

My site is a PWA, is **installed** and **has the permission to use push notifications**, but `granted` is on my **Mac** never `true`, on my Android Smartphone it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Android has push notifications enabled by default, while on iOS you have to explicitly [enable them](https://www.lifewire.com/configure-push-notifications-on-iphone-2000104) (in case you didn't yet).

When you say:

> My site is a PWA and has the permission to use push notifications

what do you mean exactly?

Push notifications are granted at client/browser level, not on the PWA. Therefore if you access the PWA with an Android device and you grant the permission to receive Notifications, the same has to be done for Safari.

If you want to learn how to cache static assets and GET Requests with service workers, you can [have a look at my article](https://dev.to/paco_ita/service-workers-and-caching-strategies-explained-step-3-m4f), where I describe different caching strategies for PWAs.

Comment: I mean, I have installed my PWA on my Mac, what i guess should make `The site has been added to home screen` true and i used `pushManager.subscribe` to subscribe to Push Notifications what should make `The site has push notifications enabled` true. But `navigator.storage.persist()` still gives me false.

Comment: As I said, you have explicitly to enable notifications on iOS. What you did is implementing the code asking for permission to send/receive notifications, but this does not mean they are enabled on iOS. That's the reason you get them on Android, as there notifications are enabled per default.

Comment: My question is about MacOS not iOS.